# Separar resposta json para tags

Tags: jquery, html, json

Pessoal estou com a seguinte chamada ajax:

```
$(".sec-tags").html(res.data.tags);
```

Ela está retornando a chamada do servidor, entretanto a chamada está vindo da seguinte forma:

```
tags: "coelho,teste,gato"
```

Tudo está vindo dentro de uma única string separado por vírgulas. Como faço para separar essas palavras e colocar cada uma dentro de uma tag html:

```
<span class="tags">minha tag aqui</span>
```

O meu HTML é:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="sec-tags">
        <span class="tags"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para separares essa string em pedaços podes fazer assim:

```
var tags = res.data.tags.split(',');
```

Porem [o teu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140963/separar-resposta-json-para-tags?noredirect=1#comment291937_140964) faz-me crer que ele é uma array, mas que aparece como string quando convertes em HTML com `$(".tags").html(res.data.tags);`.

Vou assumir que é uma array, ou seja

```
var tags = res.data.tags;
```

Assim para montar esse HTML podes fazer assim:

```
var tags = res.data.tags; // ou no caso de ser string, usa como coloquei em cima: var tags = res.data.tags.split(',');
var spans = tags.map(function(tag){
    return '<span class="tags">' + tag + '</span>';
}).join('');
$(".sec-tags").html(spans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua chamada não está vindo com JSON, e sim um texto norma.

use a seguinte linha:

```
$aux = variavel_que_recebeu_o_texto.split(",");
```

Terá um array e poderá tratar o teu resultado.

Comment: Sim, isso é apenas uma parte do resultado de um objeto. Eu fiz: var string = $(".tags").html(res.data.tags);
            var resTags = string.split(",");
            document.getElementByClassName("tags").innerHTML = resTags; mas não tive resultado.

Comment: @HitchLeonardo vc precisa de um `for` ou o `each()` para iterar os elementos, o `split()` retornar um array, pode usar o `append()` para criar um `<span>` para cada elemento.

Comment: @william eu pensei nisso, mas no meu console tem um alerta: " string.split is not a function "